# Discord.py How to DM a user from the user ID in a cog even if the user is not in the server I run the command?

Tags: discord.py

I am working on a command that removes a bug, then rewards the user with a `bug report token (bugreport)`
then dm's them.
So how do I get a User ID even if that user is not in the server that I run this command in?
the code I have for getting and dming the user:

```py
//user is gotten from a query, it is a real ID
userobj = ctx.guild.get_user(user)
dm = await userobj.create_dm()
msg = 'msg'
dm.send(msg)
```

```py
    @commands.command(name='fixbug', allises=['finishbug'],help='[Owner Only] <bugid> <reward?>')
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def killbug(self, ctx, bugid: int, reward: str = 'False', msg: str = None):
        print(bugid)
        query = await db.load(
            f'''
                SELECT * FROM buglogs
                WHERE fixedid = {bugid}
            ''')
        print(query)
        query = query[0]
        await db.query(
            f'''
                DELETE FROM buglogs
                WHERE fixedid = {bugid}
            ''')
        
        user = query[1]
        name = query[3]
        log = query[2]
        userobj = ctx.guild.get_user(user)
        
        dm = await userobj.create_dm()
        if reward == 'True' or reward == 'true' or reward == 'yes':
            await self.add_item(user, 'bugreport', 1)
            await ctx.send(f'Gave {name} A Bug Report Token, I also squashed \"{log}\" bug!')
            
            await dm.send(f"Thank you for reporting the bug: \"{log}, You have been rewarded 1 Bug Report Token, sell it for your reward!")
        else:
            await ctx.send('Squashed: {log}')
            if msg == None:
                dm.send('The bug you reported ({log}) has been resolved, thank you!')
            else:
                dm.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bot.get_user`

```py
discordUser = self.bot.get_user(user) #pass user id here
if discordUser is not None:
    #do stuff
else:
    await ctx.send('user not found')
```

Warning: this code assumes you are in a cog and have set `self.bot = bot` in the init like in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user)

### References:

- [get_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user)